# Javascript inside foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript

Suppose you have some code which includes a javascript tooltip, and a php foreach ($result as $row) loop which is calling values from an sql database like so,

```
     <?php

   foreach ($result as $row) {
       $link = $qs->link($row,'item');
       $logoImage = $qs->getLogo($row->file_id);

       echo "<ul class=\"imggrid\"><li><a class=\"ItemLink\" href=\"$link\"><img width=\"80\" height=\"80\" src=\"" . $logoImage . "\" /></a></li></ul>";

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( document ).tooltip({ hide: "true", show: "false", 
      content: function() {
        if ( jQuery(this).is( "img[src='<?php echo $logoImage ?>']" ) ) {
          return "<img class='map' src='<?php echo $logoImage ?>'><a><?php echo $qs->abbreviate($row->title,50); ?></a>";
        }
              }
    });
  });
  </script>

<?php

   }
   ?>
```

This is oversimplified but the php spits out a grid of pictures, and I want the tooltip to display a bigger version of each picture as it hovers.  Right now it only displays the first picture in the grid for all the pictures.  I am assuming it is because the script is outside the loop.  But can I throw the script in the foreach loop?

Any suggestions or help would be great.  Keep in mind I am a novice at this stuff.

EDIT:  I added the part of my code in question.

EDIT 2:  Okay I've updated this code but now it is displaying nothing.  I thought this would work since I am selecting img elements with src = $logoImage, where $logoImage spits out the address of the file.

Comment: Add your code which show, first image, so that we can debug based on that

Comment: I added it with the alteration that aaaa12345679 suggested.  This actually made the tooltip display the last image of the grid for all pictures on the grid

Comment: Is your `id` different for all images ?

Comment: If you are referring to the attribute id, the images do not have an id attribute.  But they each have their own id in the db.

Comment: Then how do you call your tooltip ?

Comment: It is a [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) tooltip, which is called from one of their scripts I downloaded.

Comment: Think about what you're doing. You're echoing a `$(document).tooltip(...)` call for every row of your results, and *all* those calls are targeted at *all* the images on the page, not the specific image of that row. Each image now has N tooltips all overlapping each other.

Comment: Ha! I see what your saying because of the element.is( "img" ) statement.  So how do I correctly target a specific image?  Can this be done inside the element.is()?  As I said I am novice at this stuff.

Comment: DCoder, please take another look.  I changed the element.is() statement to something more suitable I think.  But now the tooltip isn't even displaying.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
  // the echo sentence
  ?>
  <!-- script goes here -->
  <?php
}
```

Remember that, at any point, you can close the PHP tags and start outputting raw data (e.g., HTML) to the page.

Comment: just add to the div which contains your image  a class, and the use the javascript on that class

Comment: I did as you suggested aaaa123456789, but it still only produces the first image on the grid for each hover.  Johny I will have to look a bit more into what you suggested.

Comment: Correction, tooltip shows the last image on the grid for all grid members with that change you suggested.

Comment: I think $logoImage must be updating because the grid displays all the different images, but the tooltip only displays one image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue could be because of `id` attribute in your image tags.

You need to generate dynamic ids(may be from DB), for each image and cal the tooltip based on that.

There can not be same id use multiple times a html page.